# Time machine backup to hard drive on server

Tags: linux, time-machine

I have a linux machine that i use as a general server, I would like to be able to backup my mac to a hard drive plugged into the linux machine, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have the HD mounted in the Linux machine.
There are good instructions here:
http://code.stephenmorley.org/articles/time-machine-on-a-network-drive/

I had to make a script on the Mac and run it periodically since the Mac would disconnect from my NAS server frequently or with any updates to the Mac.

Hope this helps.